# editing one EditText field edits the other also

Tags: java, android

I have 2 EditText fields one below the other. As I try to type the data into one of the fields, auto suggestion pops up. When I select the data it suggested into one view, the other view is also getting filled up with the same data. But if I type the data manually without selecting from the suggestion, its works fine. I have not linked the 2 views in any way. What could be wrong?

The code snippet of .xml file

```
           <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtFatherName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Father Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtMotherName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edtFatherName"
            android:hint="Mother Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>
```

Here are the images showing the steps in the order.
1st Step

[image]

2nd Step

[image]

3rd Step

[image]

Comment: Please post the code that updates the text to both ```EditText```s

Comment: There is no code to update the text in the EditText. In fact there is no code associated with the edittexts. Only, on clicking some other button, I will save the data. But that is before going to the next activity. That's what I am wondering as to when I have not written any code, why is it populating the data ? The problem is, on selection of the suggested text in one edittext, the other one is getting updated as well. But if enter the text manually, it's working fine. Pls check the images I have attached .

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want suggestions please use this snippet in your editText `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions | text"`.

If one value is copied to another editText, you must thoroughly debug your code. Basically, that will not happen.

Note: Please provide some example codes to get better answers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mohan, But I do need the auto suggestion. When I say auto suggestion, Its the values I have entered earlier. Like how your device suggests you with username, email id that is used earlier when you try to login.

Comment: By the way, its not the suggestions that is coming from my app. Its the general suggestions that come for all apps on the device. Your previously entered data. Like the username, Email id, home address etc.,

Comment: Got it, Lakshmi. Can you please post your code snippet? It will be better to understand your problem

Comment: I have edited my question. please check it.